# How to scroll composite?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have got:

```
private void createTab(){

  TabItem mvTabItem = new TabItem( tabFolder, SWT.NONE );
  mvTabItem.setText( TabHeader.modelviews.getTabHeaderName() );


  Composite mvContainer = new Composite( tabFolder, SWT.V_SCROLL );
  mvContainer.setLayout( new GridLayout(1, false) );
  mvContainer.setLayoutData( new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true) );

  mvTabItem.setControl( mvContainer );

  // Selection of model views
  createSelectionGroup(mvContainer);

  // other code, more groups created
}
```

which creates tab item, adds vertical scrollbar, but scrolling is not working. Why?

Inside `createSelectionGroup(mvContainer)` there is a scrollbar as well. This one works fine, no `org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite` was applied:

```
private void createSelectionGroup(Composite parent)
{
  // Create group component.
  Group grpMVselection = new Group(parent, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
  grpMVselection.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));
  grpMVselection.setText(SelectionLabelStr);
  grpMVselection.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

  // another code, added buttons, listeners
    
  final SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(grpMVselection, SWT.VERTICAL | SWT.BORDER);
  sashForm.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

  // srolling applied 
  selectionTree = new CheckboxTreeViewer(sashForm, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.HIDE_SELECTION);
  selectionTree.getTree().setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.BEGINNING, true, true ) );
}
```

[image: screenshot]

There are similar questions publicized, but I can not apply answers to my code. I did try:

1. change `Composite mvContainer` to `ScrolledComposite`, did not help
2. insert `mvContainer` to `ScrolledComposite`, did not help

   ```
    TabItem mvTabItem = new TabItem( tabFolder, SWT.NONE );
    mvTabItem.setText( TabHeader.modelviews.getTabHeaderName() );

    final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolder, SWT.V_SCROLL );
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);

    mvTabItem.setControl(sc);

    Composite mvContainer = new Composite( sc, SWT.NONE );
    //mvContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    mvContainer.setLayout( new GridLayout(1, false) );
    mvContainer.setLayoutData( new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true) );

    sc.setContent(mvContainer);
   ```

Do children need change some property? Thanks for any hint!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to use `ScrolledComposite` for scrolling composites.

Something like:

```
final TabItem tabItem = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
tabItem.setText("Tab");

final ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(tabFolder, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
sc.setExpandVertical(true);

tabItem.setControl(sc);

final Composite scrolledComp = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
scrolledComp.setLayout(new GridLayout());

sc.setContent(scrolledComp);

// Example contents
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
  new Label(scrolledComp, SWT.LEAD).setText("Label " + i);

sc.setMinSize(scrolledComp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

TreeViewers such as CheckboxTreeViewer can do scrolling themselves, but Composites requite ScrolledComposite.

Comment: Hi [greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449), thanks for your comment! I did try something similar (you can check updated question), but did not work. I can see only blank tab.

Comment: You need to call setExpandHorizontal(true) and setMinSize in your code, see the example above.